# Criação e comunicação com daemon

Tags: php, python, linux

Tenho uma aplicação em Python onde preciso mantê-la online o tempo inteiro.

A aplicação possui um próprio console, que é onde faço a comunicação e passo parâmetros.

Entendi que posso criar o Daemon para deixar ela online o tempo inteiro, agora o problema é que ainda não entendi como passar comandos para a aplicação estando 'online'.

Tenho mais familiaridade com PHP, então estou criando o *daemon* assim. Até consigo já dar o *start*, porém ainda não faço ideia de como ter uma comunicação com ele que está com o console aberto esperando comandos.

Imagino que resolver tudo aqui será difícil, porém se puderem me passar algumas referências e um caminho eu estudo e vou compartilhando os resultados.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa procurar por uma solução de comunicação inter-processos.

Uma maneira popular que funciona de maneira similar em várias plataformas e linguagens de programação é criar um servidor de filas (MQ). Um desses é [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) e você pode ver alguns [exemplos aqui](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/tree/master/examples).

Uma outra maneira é utilizar o módulo [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) do próprio Python. Aqui vai um exemplo testado, apenas para dar uma idéia por onde começar:

#### No seu daemon, inicie o servidor que espera conexões do cliente (console)

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
import threading
import time

def processa_comando(comando):
    print 'Recebi o comando:', comando
    return {'status': 'OK', 'commando': comando}

def inicia_servidor():
    servidor = Listener(('localhost', 12345), authkey='senha')
    try:
        while True:
            # esperar conexao
            cnx = servidor.accept()
            # o codigo a seguir, em uma implementacao real,
            # poderia ser movido para uma thread nova (uma
            # para cada cliente conectado)
            print 'Client connected.'
            while True:
                # esperar comandos do cliente
                mensagem = cnx.recv()
                if mensagem['tipo'] == 'comando':
                    resposta = processa_comando(mensagem['comando'])
                    cnx.send(resposta)
                elif mensagem['tipo'] == 'exit':
                    print 'Client left.'
                    cnx.close()
                    break
    except Exception as err:
        print 'Erro', err
    finally:
        servidor.close()

# o servidor executa em uma thread separada para nao
# bloquear o programa principal
t = threading.Thread(target=inicia_servidor)
t.start()

# simulacao para mostrar que o servidor continua a
# trabalhar enquanto aguarda comandos
while True:
    print 'Servidor trabalhando...'
    time.sleep(5)
```

#### No seu cliente (console) connecte-se ao daemon

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client

def aguarda_proximo_commando():
    commando = raw_input()
    return commando

cliente = Client(('localhost', 12345), authkey='senha')
try:
    while True:
        # fica em loop ate um CTRL+C
        print 'server>',
        texto = aguarda_proximo_commando()
        cliente.send({'tipo': 'comando', 'comando': texto})
        resposta = cliente.recv()
        print '  =>', resposta
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cliente.send({'tipo': 'exit'})
except Exception as err:
    print 'Erro', err
finally:
    cliente.close()
```

#### Exemplo de execução do cliente:

```
~/teste $ python client.py 
server> ola
  => {'status': 'OK', 'commando': 'ola'}
server> tudo bem
  => {'status': 'OK', 'commando': 'tudo bem'}
server> ^C
~/teste $ python client.py 
server> ola de novo
  => {'status': 'OK', 'commando': 'ola de novo'}
server> ja vou
  => {'status': 'OK', 'commando': 'ja vou'}
server> ^C
~/teste $
```

#### Resultado do exemplo no servidor:

```
~/teste $ python server.py 
Servidor trabalhando...
Servidor trabalhando...
Client connected.
Recebi o comando: ola
Servidor trabalhando...
Recebi o comando: tudo bem
Servidor trabalhando...
Client left.
Servidor trabalhando...
Client connected.
Servidor trabalhando...
Servidor trabalhando...
Recebi o comando: ola de novo
Servidor trabalhando...
Servidor trabalhando...
Recebi o comando: ja vou
Servidor trabalhando...
Client left.
Servidor trabalhando...
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 46, in <module>
    time.sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
^C^CTerminated: 15
~/teste $
```