# Enviar arquivo .txt de um pc para outro usando serviço http

Tags: java, python, http-request

Estou precisando enviar um arquivo de um PC para outro pela rede, só que utilizando requisições **http**, para eu não ter que baixar a nível de **socket**, que dá um trabalho. Alguém se habilita a me clarear com alguma API ou exemplo de código?

**PS:**  Não sou preguiçoso, até achei algumas coisas, só que eu tinha que fazer um mini servidor e eu sou meio leigo nesse assunto.
Ah, estou usando Java e/ou Python.

Comment: Este post: [Sockets em java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42566/sockets-em-java) ou esse: [Criação e comunicação com daemon](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51087/cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-daemon/53345), talvez ajudem.

Comment: Talvez você possa instalar um servidor "pronto" em um dos lados (ex: Apache), e usar o: [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) para fazer o request. Parece ser mais fácil.

Comment: o Apache não é um "servidor pronto" para receber arquivos texto - você precisa de um aplicativo server-side que seja invocado pelo Apache que trate a requisição http que manda um arquivo.

Comment: em python tambem tem o requests no propio site do projeto tem algums exemplos http://pt.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Galera, consegui já resolver esse problema usando um mini server python e mais outros detalhes. Vocês acham interessante eu postar a solução aqui como resposta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Receber um arquivo HTTP como um request Web, sem usar um framework, não é tão trivial assim:

Para garantir a passagem dos dados do arquivo, junto com outros eventuais dados de formulário, e outras coisas que vão num post HTTP, a coisa fica bem chatinha.

Fiz um programinha em Python 3- sem usar framework, apenas usando o o módulo http.server para receber um arquivo - ele funciona, mas arranca "na marra" os dados do arquivo de dentro do post HTTP, sem fazer o parse corretamente. Certamente há dezenas de corner-cases que não são tratados (não é que não são tratados direito - simplesmente não são tratados). Em particular os dados do post são lidos como "bytes" e não tem disponíveis os métodos bacanas de Python de busca e cortar strings. Em particular faço uma gambiarra necessária: uma conversão transparente desses "bytes" para string  com o codec "latin1" - isso preserva o valor numérico de cada byte, como um caractér unicode de valor equivalente na string - e no objeto string, posso usar split, find, slices, etc...

Por outro lado, acho que fica um exemplo legal de como usar o "http.server" do Python 3 (módulo BaseHTTPServer) em Python2.

```
# coding: utf-8
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import cgi

UPLOAD_DIR = "/tmp/"

class FileSaver(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html;charset=utf-8")
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        files = []
        try: 
            raw_file_content = self.rfile.read(int( self.headers.get('content-length')))
            data = raw_file_content.decode("latin1")
            while True:
                try:
                    header, data = data.split("\r\n\r\n", 1)
                except ValueError:
                    break
                boundary_str = header.split("\r\n", 1)[0]
                if "filename" in header:
                    file_data = data.split("\r\n" + boundary_str)[0].encode("latin1")
                    filename = header.split('filename="')[1].split('"')[0]

                    with open(UPLOAD_DIR + filename, "wb") as file_:
                        file_.write(file_data)
                    files.append(filename)
                data = data[data.find(boundary_str):]
                if len(data) < 2:
                    break
        except Exception as exc:
            self.send_response(500)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain;charset=utf-8")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(str(exc).encode("utf-8"))
            raise
        self._headers()
        self.wfile.write("""<h1 style="color:red">upload of {} ok</h1>""".format(filename).encode("utf-8"))
        return

    def do_GET(self):
        self._headers()

        self.wfile.write("""<h1 style="color:red">Alô mundo!!</h1>
            <form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            arquivo: <input type="file" name="arquivo"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="ok" / >
            </form>

            """.encode("utf-8"))
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = HTTPServer(("0.0.0.0", 8000), FileSaver)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Claro que usando um framework como Flask, é *bem* mais fácil fazer isso. 
Uma view que salve um arquivo que tenha vindo num forumlário, em Flask, usando a extensão de formulários WTF (com o framework já cuidando de todos os cornercases acima) seria algo do tipo:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import flask_wtf

app = Flask(__name__)

class FileForm(form):
     file = flask_wtf.file.FileField

@route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload(form, id):
    form.file.data.save("/tmp/" + form.file.data.filename)
    return render_template(...)
```

(Esse código em Flask nao está completo e não foi testado - o em Pythno bruto acima funciona como está)

Já o codigo para postar um arquivo por HTTP - novamente, se for usando Python "cru" pode ser bem complicado - mas nesse caso, podemos usar o método "requests" que aceita um parâmetro "file" diretamente (ele recebe um dicionário com o nome do campo de arquivo e um arquivo aberto, que desejamos enviar):

```
>>> requests.post("http://localhost:8000", files={"arquivo": open("imagem.png", "rb")  } )
```

Apenas essa chamada faz o upload do arquivo para o servidorzinho da listagem 1 acima.

Agora,uma coisa é querer brincar com isso, outra é querer usar em produção - nesse caso é melhor ou usar o framework, claro, ou usar xmlrpc (ou jsonrpc) - vai ser uma ordem de grandeza mais fácil.

Comment: Fala amigo, eu mesmo futicando acabei conseguindo, e sabe o que mais? Justamente usando o `Flask`!!! Eu fiz o _sender_ em `java`, e o mini-servidor em python com flask, mas valeu cara!!